# 2 django projects, importing one model from one to another

Tags: django, django-models

My setup is Django 1.2 running via mod_wsgi under Debian Lenny.

I have a such structure:

```
/root/
    project1/appx
                 models.py
    project2/appy
                 models.py
                 management/
                           commands/
                                   mycommand.py
```

Now I want to import Foox model from project1 to project2.

What would be the easiest solution WITHOUT moving the whole project dir to Python_path ? I especially need a solution without using mod_wsgi because I will be importing this model from project1 to [custom manage.py command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) called "mycommand" in project2 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/root/project1')
from appx.models import Foox
```

Comment: but this does not work with relations (foreign keys/ManyToMany.keys)

Comment: This will import the model structure but if both projects use different databases, the data won't be shared right?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$ cd /root/project2
$ ln -s ../project1/appx
```

?